# C# WPF Application webbrowser can't run angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, wpf, firebase

I have made a `WPF` application with a browser and set it to go to a website which is using `firebase` and `angularjs`. When I run the program I get errors such as `"Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference"` and it shows the source of this error as `angular.min.js`. Another error is within the `firebase.js` file and it just says `"Script error"`. The website works perfectly on actual browsers such as Chrome or even IE11. How can I fix these errors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can we create WPF app with Angular js and html5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show me your html file where you import angular.min.js and firebase.js.
Maby can be fixed with a DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```